# Ajax formdata submission using click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this form that allows user to write an article also upload an image.

i use the ajax script below

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#publishArticle").on('submit', function() {

      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url  : "send.php",
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType : false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){
          $("#result").fadeIn();
          $("#result").html("");
          $("#result").html(response);
          $("#result").fadeOut(4000);
          if (response == "Article Published") {
            $("#publishArticle")[0].reset();
          }
        }
        });
      });
    });
```

It works well. then i decided to have another button that drafts an article...

am trying to use an onclick event to differenciate between them. but it's not going through...

//Publish

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#publish").click(function(){

      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url  : "send.php",
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType : false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){
          $("#result").fadeIn();
          $("#result").html("");
          $("#result").html(response);
          $("#result").fadeOut(4000);
          if (response == "Article Published") {
            $("#publishArticle")[0].reset();
          }
        }
        });
      });
    });
```

//Drafts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#draft").click(function(){

      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url  : "draft.php",
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType : false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){
          $("#result").fadeIn();
          $("#result").html("");
          $("#result").html(response);
          $("#result").fadeOut(4000);
          if (response == "Article Drafted") {
            $("#publishArticle")[0].reset();
          }
        }
        });
      });
    });
```

Please help me out...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a custom click handler to all buttons, and that way you can check which button is clicked before submitting the form:

Javascript:

```
$("#my-form button").click(function(event){
    
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
    event.preventDefault()// cancel form submission
    if($(this).attr("value")=="button-publish"){
      //do button 1 thing
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url  : "send.php",
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType : false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){
          $("#result").fadeIn();
          $("#result").html("");
          $("#result").html(response);
          $("#result").fadeOut(4000);
          if (response == "Article Published") {
            $("#publishArticle")[0].reset();
          }
        }
      });
    }
    
    if($(this).attr("value")=="button-draft"){
      //do button 2 thing
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url  : "draft.php",
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType : false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){
          $("#result").fadeIn();
          $("#result").html("");
          $("#result").html(response);
          $("#result").fadeOut(4000);
          if (response == "Article Drafted") {
            $("#publishArticle")[0].reset();
          }
        }
      });
    }
    
    $("#my-form").submit(); // If you want to submit the form
});
```